# If abc=1 then $\frac{3a^2+2b^2}{a(a^2+b^2)}+\frac{3b^2+2c^2}{b(b^2+c^2)}+\frac{3c^2+2a^2}{c(c^2+a^2)}\ge\frac{15}{2}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0: abc=1.$ Prove that: $$\frac{3a^2+2b^2}{a(a^2+b^2)}+\frac{3b^2+2c^2}{b(b^2+c^2)}+\frac{3c^2+2a^2}{c(c^2+a^2)}\ge\frac{15}{2}$$

I am really stuck now. My approach using AM-GM then I gained: $$(3a^2+2b^2)(3b^2+2c^2)(3c^2+2a^2)\ge\frac{125}{8}(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)$$ which is homogenous inequality. Unfortunately, this is wrong one.

Also by AM-GM: $3a^2+2b^2=a^2+4\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\ge5\sqrt[5]{a^2\frac{(a^2+b^2)}{16}}$ The remained inequality is incorrect: $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[5]{\frac{2}{a^3(a^2+b^2)}}\ge3.$$
Is there any nice proof for the problem?. Thanks for your time and knowledge.

Comment: My guess is you split the fraction $\frac{3a^2+2b^2}{a(a^2+b^2)}$ into $\frac{2}{a}+\frac{a^2}{a(a^2+b^2)}$, do that for all of the fractions then with the ones with the squared terms on top, apply the Cauchy-Schwarz in Engel form and see where that takes you

Comment: Then for $\frac{2}{a}+\frac{2}{b}+\frac{2}{c}$ you can use AM-GM to get that that is greater than $6$

Comment: It seems not effective. Thanks

Comment: LHS $=\frac{2}{a}+\frac{2}{b}+\frac{2}{c}+\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{b}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{c}{c^2+a^2}$

Next, using two separate cases of AM-GM

LHS $≥3\sqrt[3]{\frac{8}{abc}}+3\sqrt[3]{\frac{abc}{(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)}}$ 
$=6+3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)}}$

Now use $a^2+b^2≥2ab$ to deduce that $(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)≥8a^2b^2c^2=8$

Therefore $6+3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)}}≤6+3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{8}}$ 

$=6+3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{8}}$
$=\frac{15}{2}$, which is your required result

Comment: Your approach is reverse. Do you prove or disprove?

Comment: I dunno, maybe the person who created the question got the signs mixed up because I arrived at the exact number which shouldn't happen for a faulty method if the premise is true

Comment: Or maybe you could prove the AM-GM difference is greater than the result derived from the final sign switch which would mean the equality still holds true.

Comment: Now, I get it. Thank you very much